# Android Retrofit регистрация API дает пустой результат,не регистрируется

Tags: android, retrofit

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @POST("?act=register")
    Call<RegResponse> register(@Query ("email") String email , @Query("fullname") String fullname , @Query("password") String password);
}

String name = mSignUpName.getText().toString();
String pass = mSignUpPasswordView.getText().toString();
email = mSignUpEmailView.getText().toString();

ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<RegResponse> call = apiInterface.register(name,email,pass);
call.enqueue(new Callback<RegResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<RegResponse> call, Response<RegResponse> response) {
        showProgress(false);
        Log.d("Log","True");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<RegResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        showProgress(false);
        Log.d("Log","Error" + t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

вы хотите передавать `POST` или `GET`? 
Если `POST`, то вместо `@Query` вам следует использовать `@RequestBody`.
Если все же `GET`, то напишите как должен выглядеть запрос

Составить можно его так:

```
RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("email", email)
                    .add("fullname", fullname)
                    .add("password", password)
                    .build();
```

Comment: у меня апи такой..?act=register&email=test@gmail.com&fullname=Naka&password=123456

Comment: json {"info":[{"success":false,"object":"","errors":["\u041f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c \u0441 \u0442\u0430\u043a\u0438\u043c E-mail \u0443\u0436\u0435 \u0441\u0443\u0449\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0443\u0435\u0442."]}]}

Comment: как правильно запросить POST ?

Comment: тогда вам надо использовать вместо аннотации `@POST` - `@GET`

Comment: так @GET("?act=register")
    Call<RegResponse> register(@Query("fullname") String name,@Query("email") String email,@Query("password") String pass);

Comment: лучше `@GET("") Call<RegResponse> register(@Query("act") act, @Query("fullname") String name,@Query("email") String email,@Query("password") String pass);` и передавать register в качестве параметра